# how to set datetime in navbar for all my template in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, navbar

I have 3 htmls in my django project.

```
 - base.html
 - navbar.html
 - home.html
```

I want set Datetime field in Navbar cause when i'm in home. i can see time there.i look for something like `{{ request.user }}` so i use that in Navbar.

I know i can define :

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

for define Datetime.

but i cant define any context for Navbar cause that don't have def in
Views.py 
what can i do ?
tnx for response.

Comment: What do you mean of `but i cant define any context for Navbar cause that don't have def in Views.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/_modules/django/template/context_processors/) to set a global variable.

---

## How to use a Context Processor in Django

### Create a function that returns current time

*contextprocessor.py*

```
from datetime import datetime
def time_now(request):
    return {'time_now': datetime.now()}
```

### Register the function as a context processor in django

*settings.py*

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
...
'contextprocessor.time_now',
)
```

### Use the context processor globally

*base.html*

```
  <ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link">{{ time_now | date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: it 's very help me tnx a lot .